# Unable to access Widget ids in Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
KV = """
MDScreen:
    submit_btn: submit_btn
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: submit_btn
        text:'Submit'
        on_press: app.btn()
"""
class Test(MDApp):
    submit_btn = ObjectProperty(None)
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    def btn(self):
        print(self.submit_btn.state)

Test().run()
```

On pressing the button, I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'state'
```

I am unable to access `id` of widgets. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty similar to your previous question a few minutes ago: you have not set `self.submit_btn` to anything except None. It looks like you tried to in the kv rule, but you've actually set the property of the `MdScreen` instance which is your root widget, accessed as `self.root.submit_btn`.